# SQL connection from Visual C++ Windows Form project

Tags: c++, sql-server, visual-studio, visual-c++, sql-server-2014

I'm very new to C++. just created a **C++ Windows Forms** project using Visual Studio Community 2015. And used the below main function to obtain a SQL connection.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <sqlext.h>
#include <sqltypes.h>
#include <sql.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

#define SQL_RESULT_LEN 240
#define SQL_RETURN_CODE_LEN 1000
    //define handles and variables
    SQLHANDLE sqlConnHandle;
    SQLHANDLE sqlStmtHandle;
    SQLHANDLE sqlEnvHandle;
    SQLWCHAR retconstring[SQL_RETURN_CODE_LEN];
    //initializations
    sqlConnHandle = NULL;
    sqlStmtHandle = NULL;
    //allocations
    if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &sqlEnvHandle))
        goto COMPLETED;
    if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLSetEnvAttr(sqlEnvHandle, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (SQLPOINTER)SQL_OV_ODBC3, 0))
        goto COMPLETED;
    if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, sqlEnvHandle, &sqlConnHandle))
        goto COMPLETED;
    //output
    cout << "Attempting connection to SQL Server...";
    cout << "\n";
    //connect to SQL Server  

    switch (SQLDriverConnect(sqlConnHandle,
        NULL,
        (SQLWCHAR*)L"Server=P2005\SQLEXPRESS2014;Database=CPPDB;User Id=myuid;Password=mypswd;",

        SQL_NTS,
        retconstring,
        1024,
        NULL,
        SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT)) {
    case SQL_SUCCESS:
        cout << "Successfully connected to SQL Server";
        cout << "\n";
        break;
    case SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO:
        cout << "Successfully connected to SQL Server";
        cout << "\n";
        break;
    case SQL_INVALID_HANDLE:
        cout << "Could not connect to SQL Server";
        cout << "\n";
        goto COMPLETED;
    case SQL_ERROR:
        cout << "Could not connect to SQL Server";
        cout << "\n";
        goto COMPLETED;
    default:
        break;
    }
    //if there is a problem connecting then exit application
    if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, sqlConnHandle, &sqlStmtHandle))
        goto COMPLETED;
    //output
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "Executing T-SQL query...";
    cout << "\n";
    //if there is a problem executing the query then exit application
    //else display query result
    if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLExecDirect(sqlStmtHandle, (SQLWCHAR*)L"SELECT @@VERSION", SQL_NTS)) {
        cout << "Error querying SQL Server";
        cout << "\n";
        goto COMPLETED;
    }
    else {
        //declare output variable and pointer
        SQLCHAR sqlVersion[SQL_RESULT_LEN];
        SQLINTEGER ptrSqlVersion;
        while (SQLFetch(sqlStmtHandle) == SQL_SUCCESS) {
            SQLGetData(sqlStmtHandle, 1, SQL_CHAR, sqlVersion, SQL_RESULT_LEN, &ptrSqlVersion);
            //display query result
            cout << "\nQuery Result:\n\n";
            cout << sqlVersion << endl;
        }
    }
    //close connection and free resources
COMPLETED:
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, sqlStmtHandle);
    SQLDisconnect(sqlConnHandle);
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, sqlConnHandle);
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, sqlEnvHandle);
    //pause the console window - exit when key is pressed
    cout << "\nPress any key to exit...";
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

When I build and run the above code, It always gives "Could not connect to SQL Server".
SQL connection string is given below as,

```
"Server=P2005\SQLEXPRESS2014;Database=CPPDB;User Id=myuid;Password=mypswd;"
```

I got the above connection string format from [this](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2014/) link.
And I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2014 via SQL Management Studio.

Note : It always triggers the SQL_ERROR case in switch.
I'm trying to trace the error. But I didn't get any luck.

Why this occurs?

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: if you want to add something to your question, don't add comment, but edit your question. I think you should print more information about the exception to see what details you get about the error. If there is stack trace in C++, try look into that

Comment: Can you show the ORIGINAL error message, not yours "Could not connect to SQL Server"

Comment: Thanks Flicker, I already modified it. But I couldn't get the erroe stack trace yet.

Comment: @sepunic Trying it. I'm very new to the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is a suggestion.**

Try Visual C++ MFC Template.

Include belows.

```
//For CDatabase class
#include "odbcinst.h"
#include "afxdb.h"
//
```

Do below stuff anywhere you want.

```
    CDatabase database;
    CString SqlString;
    CString strID, strName, strAge;
    CString sDriver = L"ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server";
    CString sDsn;
    int iRec = 0;

    // Build ODBC connection string
    sDsn.Format(L"ODBC;DRIVER={%s};DSN='';DBQ=%s;DATABASE=MYDBNAME", sDriver, NULL);
    TRY{
        // Open the database
        database.Open(NULL,false,false,sDsn);

    SqlString = "INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (id,name,age) VALUES (1,'Sanjaya',25)";
    database.ExecuteSQL(SqlString);
    // Close the database
    database.Close();
    }CATCH(CDBException, e) {
        // If a database exception occured, show error msg
        AfxMessageBox(L"Database error: " + e->m_strError);
    }
    END_CATCH;
```

You should create ODBC Datasource, and it should specify as "ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server".
I'm using VS Community 2015 and SQL Server 2014.

Comment: I'm not using a trusted connection. How to implement that using connection string?

Comment: You can modify the string like, `ODBC;DRIVER={%s};DSN='';DBQ=%s;DATABASE=MYDBNAME;UID=myuid;PWD=mypwd;` .Try and try. These are not brain surgeries. hah...

Answer (score 0):

just add a backslash in your instance name
P2005\SQLEXPRESS2014
P2005\\SQLEXPRESS2014